# Android Studio 2.0 : Gradle DSL method not found: 'classpath()' error(27,0)

Tags: android, plugins, gradle, classpath, dsl

First of all, I've read all other solution posts and So far, none has worked.
and I'm using Android Studio 2.0

Error:
Error:(27, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'classpath()'
Possible causes:

The project 'Sailu'sFood' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

here is build.gradle(app) :

```
     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

          android
          {
            compileSdkVersion 23
            buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.kandarp.food"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
          }
           buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
              proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),         'proguard-rules.pro'
              }
             }
         }

                  dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
            }

             apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

here is build.gradle(top level) :

```
             buildscript {


            repositories {
                jcenter()
            }

                dependencies {

                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'

            }



        }
              allprojects {
            repositories {
                jcenter()
            }
        }
            task clean(type: Delete) {
            delete rootProject.buildDir
        }


            apply plugin: 'project-report'
            apply plugin: 'application'
```

It'd really great if someone could point out what's the mistake

Comment: I know nothing about errors of this nature, but that apostrophe (Sailu'sFood) is making my spidey sense tingle...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove this line from `app/build.gradle` from the `dependencies` block.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'
```

Then you have to move the line in the `buildscript` block (in the top-level file or in the module file):

```
 buildscript {
       repositories {
            jcenter()
       }
      dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'
      }
}
```

Comment: Indeed removing the extra classpath from the second .gradle solved it for moe. Can't have it in two places (only top level).